# how can i commit single cell from running notebook to github?

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook

Is there way to commit cell by cell and not the entire notebook after it's ready?

How can i commit from inside the running jupyter notebook?

**jupyter notebook cell**

some code in cell

```
git commit -m "done EDA analysis"
```

Comment: You can commit the entire notebook only since it's a single file but you can make multiple commits per cell.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, so i can't do commit = cell and build notebook like this in my git profile?

Comment: You can. However, each commit will be a change to the single `.ipynb` file.